# Corner radius text field Swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, textview, app

Есть обычное текстовое поле, я могу поставить радиус для всех границы и все в порядке. Но моя задача сделать два разных радиуса для левой и правой стороны. Когда я задаю , то только одна сторона принимает заданный радиус, а вторая просто игнорируется и остается  квадратная.

Есть следующий код.

```
 func radius(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                clipsToBounds = true
                layer.cornerRadius = radius
                layer.maskedCorners = CACornerMask(rawValue: corners.rawValue)
            }
    }

 func setupTextField() {

        textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
        textField.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9019607843, green: 0.9019607843, blue: 0.9019607843, alpha: 1)
        textField.borderStyle = .none
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 2

        textField.radius([.topLeft, .bottomLeft], radius: 20)
        textField.radius([.topRight, .bottomRight], radius: 10)

    }
}
```

Comment: Она остается квадратная,  потому что второй вызов метода `Radius` переписывает результат первого. Как вариант можно рисовать свои углы и границы, используя например `UIBezierPath` или `CAShapeLayer`, если будет время, попробую дать пример. Кстати имена переменных и функций в свифте принято писать с маленькой буквы, чтобы не путать с типами

Comment: Спасибо, за подсказку, буду ждать пример и искать решение.

Answer (score 1):

Вот набросал класс с поддержкой удобной раздельной отрисовки углов, ибо встроенными средствами можно либо закруглить все углы с помощью `layer.cornerRadius`, либо отдельные с помощью `layer.maskedCorners`, однако при этом невозможно сделать углы с разным закруглением

```
import UIKit

class MyTextField: UITextField {

    struct Corner {
        var radius: CGFloat = 0
        var rectCorner: UIRectCorner
    }

    var corners: [Corner]?
    var borderColor = UIColor.lightGray
    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 1

    /// Используем для отрисовки - на случай
    /// если массив `corners` инициализирован не всеми 4-мя углами
    private lazy var cornersInternal: [Corner] = {
        [customCorner(.topLeft),
         customCorner(.topRight),
         customCorner(.bottomRight),
         customCorner(.bottomLeft)]
    }()

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        if borderStyle != .none {
            return
        }

        borderColor.setStroke()

        let borderPath = UIBezierPath()
        borderPath.lineWidth = borderWidth

        var path = UIBezierPath()
        let offset = borderPath.lineWidth / 2

        for corner in cornersInternal {

            if (corner.radius > frame.height / 2 || corner.radius > frame.width / 2) {
                print("corner radius \(corner.radius) too big")
            }

            switch corner.rectCorner {

            case .topLeft:
                if corner.radius == 0 {
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: offset, y: offset))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width - customCorner(.topRight).radius - offset, y: offset))
                } else {
                    path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: corner.radius + offset, y: corner.radius + offset), radius: corner.radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 3 / 2, clockwise: true)
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width - customCorner(.topRight).radius - offset, y: offset))
                }

                borderPath.append(path)

            case .topRight:
                if corner.radius == 0 {
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width - offset, y: offset))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width - offset, y: frame.height - customCorner(.bottomRight).radius - offset))
                } else {
                    path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.width - corner.radius - offset, y: corner.radius + offset), radius: corner.radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi * 3 / 2, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width - offset, y: frame.height - customCorner(.bottomRight).radius - offset))
                }

                borderPath.append(path)

            case .bottomRight:
                if corner.radius == 0 {
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width - offset, y: frame.height - offset))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: offset + customCorner(.bottomLeft).radius, y: frame.height - offset))
                } else {
                    path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.width - corner.radius - offset, y: frame.height - corner.radius - offset), radius: corner.radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, clockwise: true)
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: customCorner(.bottomLeft).radius + offset, y: frame.height - offset))
                }

                borderPath.append(path)

            case .bottomLeft:
                if corner.radius == 0 {
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: offset, y: frame.height - offset))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: offset, y: offset + customCorner(.topLeft).radius))
                } else {
                    path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: corner.radius + offset, y: frame.height - corner.radius - offset), radius: corner.radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: offset, y: customCorner(.topLeft).radius + offset))
                }

                borderPath.append(path)

            default:
                break
            }
        }

        borderPath.stroke()

    }

    // Увеличиваем размер поля если borderStyle = .none
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        corners != nil
            ? bounds.insetBy(dx: 8, dy: 8)
            : super.textRect(forBounds: bounds)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        corners != nil
            ? textRect(forBounds: bounds)
            : super.editingRect(forBounds: bounds)
    }

    private func setup() {
        // делаем границу невидимой, так как в противном случае
        // кастомная граница скрывается под встроенной
        borderStyle = .none
    }

    private func customCorner(_ corner: UIRectCorner) -> Corner {
        let result = corners?.filter{$0.rectCorner == corner}.first
        return (result != nil) ? result! : Corner(rectCorner: corner)
    }

}
```

Пример

```
textField.corners = [
    MyTextField.Corner(radius: 16, rectCorner: .topLeft),
    MyTextField.Corner(radius: 8, rectCorner: .topRight),
    MyTextField.Corner(radius: 8, rectCorner: .bottomRight),
]
```

Comment: Больше спасибо,  сейчас попробую сделать